# Sketching Images of sets under a function in Complex Plane

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to know how I would be able to sketch the image of a function in the complex plane. Say I was considering the set A = {z = x + iy: x in (0,1) y in (0,1)} under the function f(z)=z^2. How would I sketch its image? The domain is clear and simple, but the issue with the image is I cannot work out how to sketch it, as I have, on an argand diagram, the real part in the x direction, and the imaginary part in the y direction, so where would the output value of f(z) be plotted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry this hasn't posted properly: the set A = {z=x+iy:0<x<1, 0<y<1} under the function f(z)=z^2. How would I then sketch this, on what sort of diagram and where would I plot the output points of f(z)?

Comment: Why don't you edit your question?

Comment: Thanks, have done, didn't realise it was an option!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x+yi)=x^2-y^2+2xyi$. So, consider the line segments:

- from $0$ to $1$;
- from $1$ to $1+i$;
- from $1+i$ to $i$;
- from $i$ to $0$

and see whr $f$ maps them into. For instance, the second segment is $\bigl\{1+ti\,|\,t\in[0,1]\bigr\}$ and $f(1+ti)=1-t^2+2ti$. So, you get a parabolic arc.

Now, see what you get from the other three segmens. Doinf his will give you the boundary of $f(A)$.

Comment: My issue is, once I've found all the boundaries, how do I plot them. Because I have the real and imaginary parts, plus the output value of f(z)?

Comment: I don't understand your doubt. If you know both $\operatorname{Re}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)$ and $\operatorname{Im}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)$, then what else do you need to know $f(z)$?